# How to make a CountDownTimer that runs only one time Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, countdowntimer

I am trying to make a CountDownTimer for my Android app, but every time I try to start it using just `timer.start()`, it starts multiple timers. I don't know why.

My code for this is:

```
fun DissapearSkip() {
    skipTimeButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    exoSkip.visibility = View.GONE
    skipTimeText.text = new.skipType.getType()
    skipTimeButton.setOnClickListener {
        exoPlayer.seekTo((new.interval.endTime * 1000).toLong())
    }
    val timer = object : CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            println(millisUntilFinished)
            if (new == null) {
                skipTimeButton.visibility = View.GONE
                exoSkip.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                dissappeared = false
                return
            }
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            val skip = currentTimeStamp
            skipTimeButton.visibility = View.GONE
            exoSkip.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            dissappeared = true
        }
    }
    timer.start()
}
```

also the new variable is for getting the timestamp type and info

Comment: What is the new variable ?

Comment: Please provide more code.